# determining if at least one pair of fields are filled out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So in my rails app I have a column of text boxes in pairs.  There are 4 pairs of textboxes.

Just one of these pairs of text box needs to be filled out (with both textboxes in that pair filled out) for it to be valid.

So I'm trying to loop through them all and add them to a multi dimensional array and to check that at least one row(?) in the array has both values.

```
  def no__values?
    all_values = Array.new
    txt_a_values = Array.new
    txt_b_values = Array.new

    self.item.line_items.each do |item|
      txt_a_values << item.single.nil? # this is a value from the text box a
      txt_b_values << item.aggregate.nil? # this is a value from the text box b
    end

    all_values << txt_a_values #create multi dimensional array
    all_values << txt_b_values

    all_values.each do |v|
      ??? # there needs to be one pair in the array which has both values
    end
  end
```

So it should create an array like this

```
[true][true] # both textboxes are nil
[false][false] # both textboxes have values
[true][true] # both textboxes are nil
[true][true] # both textboxes are nil
```

the above scenario is valid since there is one pair which BOTH have values

I really don't like the way I'm progressing with this, so I',m looking for some help.

Comment: Can you explain (in an edit to your question) what "item.single" and "item.aggregate" are please?

Comment: I have updated but they are just values from the textboxes, so in column A, they are the single textboxes, column B they are aggregate text boxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you do something like this:

```
def no__values?
  self.item.line_items.each do |item|
    return false if !item.single.nil? && !item.aggregate.nil?      
  end

  true
end
```

That will return `false` when both values of a pair isn't null, and returns `true` if each pair had at least one null value.

Edit:
Based on the method name I didn't create the array and instead returns false/true directly.

Comment: I think this is correct, I have tested and it works fine.  I was over-thinking it I guess..  the method originally had item.single.nil? && item.aggregate.nil, but all I needed to do was loop...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the following snippets to solve your problems. I have done it with little simplification. Please let me know if you are looking for this.

```
def no__values?

    all_values = []

    self.item.line_items.each do |item|
      all_values << [item.single.nil?, item.aggregate.nil?]
    end

    all_values.each do |v|
      puts v # [true, false] or [true, true], [false, false]....
    end
  end
```